# AngularJS call function when a div is scrolled within (x) pixels from bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to work with this [`AngularJS infinite-scroll`](https://github.com/sparkalow/angular-infinite-scroll) directive. Here's the source:

```
angular.module('infiniteScroll', [])
    .directive('infiniteScroll', [ "$window", function ($window) {
        return {
            link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var offset = parseInt(attrs.threshold) || 0;
                var e = element[0];

                element.bind('scroll', function () {
                    if (scope.$eval(attrs.canLoad) && e.scrollTop + e.offsetHeight >= e.scrollHeight - offset) {
                        scope.$apply(attrs.infiniteScroll);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This appears to work only for elements which are contained in a scrollbox. [Here's a Plunker which demonstrates this.](http://plnkr.co/edit/jxqxPGifGKyuT54NiDMb?p=preview)

However, I'd like to be able to apply this simple directive to DOM elements which are static, calling `scope.$apply(attrs.infiniteScroll)` when the element nears the bottom of the window's scroll.

Any ideas on how to modify the directive to allow for this? I've tried changing the `e.scrollTop` to `window.scrollTop` but to no avail, this is a little beyond my current skill level unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that I got your question right. If you want to have a directive which calls a function, if a certain DOM element comes close to the visible area of the whole window, how about a directive like this:

```
myApp.directive('scrollTrigger', function($window) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var offset = parseInt(attrs.threshold) || 0;
            var e = jQuery(element[0]);
            var doc = jQuery(document);
            angular.element(document).bind('scroll', function() {
                if (doc.scrollTop() + $window.innerHeight + offset > e.offset().top) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.scrollTrigger);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

With this element somewhere below the visible area in your HTML:

```
<div scroll-trigger="scrollEventCallback()" threshold="100">Trigger element</div>
```

The function `scrollEventCallback()` gets called, if it is 100 pixel or less below the currently visible area of the document. Please note, that I used jQuery in this example, so for this to work you will have to include it as well. I hope this is what you asked for.